# scalafx.animation.Timeline not working as expected

Tags: scala, scalafx

I've started to try out the ScalaFX API few days ago. To learn the usage of this API I'm looking at the examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/tree/master/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx). For testing out the features of the `TimeLine` class I used this example: [ScalaFXAnimation](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/blob/master/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx/JavaFXAnimation.scala).

The code to define a TimeLine object is looking like this in the example:

```
val timeline = new Timeline {
  cycleCount = Timeline.Indefinite
  autoReverse = true
  keyFrames = Seq(
    at (2 s) {rect1.x -> 200d tween Interpolator.EASE_IN},
    at (4 s) {rect1.x -> 300d},
    at (3 s) {rect2.y -> 100d tween Interpolator.EASE_BOTH},
    at (4 s) {rect2.y -> 300d},
    at (4 s) {rect2.width -> 300d tween Interpolator.EASE_OUT}
  )
}
```

If I try to do this in my own project I recieve some compile errors like:

```
Error:(58, 5) not found: value cycleCount
```

The values `autoReverse`, `keyFrames` and `s` are also not found.
I did not set up the project and its structure by myself but cloned an "Hello world"-project from GitHub: [scalafx-hello-world](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx-hello-world). This project and compiled properly.

Could it be a bug in ScalaFX? Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

EDIT2: Complete Code

```
package hello

import scalafx.animation.{Timeline, Interpolator}
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
import scalafx.Includes._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object ScalaFXHelloWorld extends JFXApp {

  val rect1 = new Rectangle {
    width = 100
    height = 200
    fill = Color.Red
  }

  val rect2 = new Rectangle {
    width = 200
    height = 120
    fill = Color.Green
  }

  val timeline = Timeline {
    cycleCount = Timeline.Indefinite
    autoReverse = true
    keyFrames = Seq(
      at (2 s) {rect1.x -> 200d tween Interpolator.EASE_IN},
      at (4 s) {rect1.x -> 300d},
      at (3 s) {rect2.y -> 100d tween Interpolator.EASE_BOTH},
      at (4 s) {rect2.y -> 300d},
      at (4 s) {rect2.width -> 300d tween Interpolator.EASE_OUT}
    )
  }

  timeline.play()
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene {
      content = List(rect1, rect2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code above is taken straight from an example that works correctly. Your problem, possibly, is with includes that are bringing JavaFX rather than ScalaFX classes. Can you post a complete piece of code that you have problem with, with "includeds"?

Comment: No I used the same imports as the example. Made an edit to the post with the imports

Comment: Code you posted so far, looks fine. Though those are just fragments, the issue is somewhere else. Can you post complete example that can be used to reproduce your compilation error?

Comment: Made another edit with the complete source code - I think it's quite the same as in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version you are missing `new` in front of `Timeline`. It should be:

```
val timeline = new Timeline { 
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. Now it works, but IntelliJ still tells me that it `cannot resolve symbol s`. But thats maybe a problem with my IDE...

Comment: @MarioP.Waxenegger I know it's a little late, but I had the same problem. The way to fix it is to change `1 s` to use a float or double such as `1.0 s`.