# Type mismatch on TableView example

Tags: scalafx

I got another weird error trying out the examples from the scalafx-repo. This time I copied the whole file. But I still got the following error:

```
Error:(26, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn[hello.Person,String]
 required: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[hello.Person, ?]
          new TableColumn[Person, String] {
          ^
```

I wonder why this ScalaFX object requires a JavaFX object. The approach was like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630476/scalafx-animation-timeline-not-working-as-expected). I cloned the hello-world from the scalafx-repository.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the implicit conversion from ScalaFX's `TableColumn` to JavaFX's `TableColumn` is not in scope. Add 
`import TableColumn._` to your list of imports and you should be fine.